# Passing defined variable through different scenarios is not working

Tags: java, karate

Trying to pass a reference of the response of a POST scenario to another scenario with PATCH method and changing one of the properties and getting errors. Debbuging the source code i found that when Scripts.assign is called for one scenario, the variable scope doesn't pass to the another scenario.

- Karate version: 0.5.0
- Java version: 1.8

Full feature of the test:

```
Feature: Products CRUD Test

Background: 
  * url demoBaseUrl

Scenario: fetch some products
  Given path 'products'
  When method get
  Then status 200
  And assert response.size() === 6

Scenario: add a product
  Given path 'products'
  And request {name: 'Iphone 7 Plus 128GB', description: 'Iphone 7 Plus Space Gray 128GB' }
  When method post
  Then status 200
  And match response contains { id: '#number', name: 'Iphone 7 Plus 128GB', description: 'Iphone 7 Plus Space Gray 128GB'}
  And def newProduct = response

Scenario: update a product
  Given path 'products'
  And def payload = {name: '#(newProduct.name)', description: '#(newProduct.description)'}
  And set payload $.id = #(newProduct.id)
  And match payload.id == (newProduct.id)
  And request payload
  When method patch
  Then status 200
  And match response contains {name: 'New Product Iphone 7'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design - if you need variables to be in the scope for all `Scenario`s within a feature, move it to the `Background`. And if you want this variable to be initialized only once, look at the `callonce` keyword.

Comment: I try to move the def var to the background but the assign occurs twice. I try to def a scope variable at background but at each scenario evaluation, the scope var reinicializes. With call once at def scope var this problem will be solved?

Comment: How can i declare a variable with callonce at background?

Comment: @ViniciusSouza can you look at the karate demos  - one of the examples is for callonce: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo

Comment: Solved the issue making both calls (POST and then PATCH) on the same feature.

Comment: Can you please share the solutions?

Comment: @Rahul can you please read the second paragraph after the heading "Script Structure" here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas .I thought of Scenarios to be like test steps.But this makes sense.