# Scope of any element/object of a response json is within the scenario only

Tags: karate

Scenario: Generenate jwt and check status
Given path '/sdk/jwt'

```
header Authorization = call read('jwt.js') { token: 'e68c82a665847c', secret: 'f08f06f1f41f4479854c' }
```

When method get
Then status 200
And def tkn = response
Scenario: Get project meta info for an instance
Given path '/meta/project'
And header Authorization = JWT tkn #which the response of 1st scenario.
When method get
Then the is status 200

But tkn value is not coming in the second scenario.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448351/passing-defined-variable-through-different-scenarios-is-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing defined variable through different scenarios is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448351/passing-defined-variable-through-different-scenarios-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Define in background, it will work as before test