# Reusing variable defined in one scenario in another

Tags: rest, karate

I assigned JSON response to a variable in the first scenario and I wanna use the same variable in other scenarios. Note that first scenario gets the response and assigns it to the variable defined in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing defined variable through different scenarios is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448351/passing-defined-variable-through-different-scenarios-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to do the assignment in the `Background:` itself in order for it to be re-usable across multiple scenarios.

Please take the time to read through the documentation and demo examples, really.